# Joomla not redirecting after readfile download

Tags: redirect, joomla, download, state, joomla3.0

I'm trying to get a controller task in my joomla component to download a file after the form is submitted and validated, then it should clear the state and redirect back to a blank form.  For some reason it is not redirecting - can anyone shed any light on why?

```
ob_end_clean();
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .basename(JPATH_BASE."/images/".$filename) . ";");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Connection: close");
readfile(JPATH_BASE."/images/".$filename);

// Clear the profile id from the session.
$app->setUserState('com_mycomponent.edit.thisform.id', null);

// Redirect to the list screen.
$this->setMessage(JText::_('SUCCESS'));
$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_($item->link, false));

// Flush the data from the session.
$app->setUserState('com_mycomponent.edit.thisform.data', null);
```

EDIT TO ADD:

`readfile()` seems to stop the header in it's tracks.  In the view I have an if statement that checks if their is a success message and then displays it.  I put the readfile there but it still stops the redirect.

Can anyone think of an alternative way to have a user download the file without using readfile?

Comment: What is it currently doing, staying on the same page? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Form submits, saves to database and file downloads but then does not redirect so the form data stays.  If I remove the block of code that downloads the file it works fine and the form redirects and clears the state so I get a clean form again.

Comment: apparently `readfile()` stops the headers which is probably the reason why the redirecting isn't working. You might need to change how it works and force the download after the redirect

Comment: Is there a way of copying the headers before the readfile and then re-instating them?

Comment: I would have to do some testing of my own but try putting `readfile(JPATH_BASE."/images/".$filename);` at the bottom of your script

Comment: Hi Lodder - that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I ended up just creating a controller task with the download code and then created a link to that controller task that would show on success after the form was saved and redirected.  It's a shame there isn't another way initiate a download that doesn't involve readfile or messing with headers. - Many thanks to Lodder for taking time as always though.